# Userinfo Command shows wrong status of person

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a bot in discord.py but when I run the userinfo command, it shows that the person is offline even though they are online or on dnd. Here is the code

````
@client.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    """Displays user information."""
    if not user: # this command took forever to redo for the no user lol
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Your info.", color=0x176cd5)
        embed.add_field(name="Username", value=ctx.message.author.name + "#" + ctx.message.author.discriminator, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="ID", value=ctx.message.author.id, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Status", value=ctx.message.author.status, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Highest role", value=ctx.message.author.top_role)
        embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=len(ctx.message.author.roles))
        embed.add_field(name="Joined", value=ctx.message.author.joined_at)
        embed.add_field(name="Created", value=ctx.message.author.created_at)
        embed.add_field(name="Bot?", value=ctx.message.author.bot)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.message.author, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="{}'s info".format(user), color=0x176cd5)
        embed.add_field(name="Username", value=user.name + "#" + user.discriminator, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="ID", value=user.id, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Status", value=user.status, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Highest role", value=user.top_role)
        embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=len(user.roles))
        #embed.add_field(name="Game", value=user.game)
        embed.add_field(name="Joined", value=user.joined_at)
        embed.add_field(name="Created", value=user.created_at)
        embed.add_field(name="Bot?", value=user.bot)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.message.author, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need the presence intent for this

you can get the intents with this

```py
bot = commands.Bot(("prefix"), intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

there is also a better way of defaulting the user to ctx.author if no user is inputted

```py
@bot.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    """Displays user information."""
    if user == None: ##if no user is inputted
        user = ctx.author ##defines user as the author of the message
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{}'s info".format(user), color=0x176cd5)
    embed.add_field(name="Username", value=user.name + "#" + user.discriminator, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="ID", value=user.id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Status", value=user.status, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Highest role", value=user.top_role)
    embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=len(user.roles))
    embed.add_field(name="Game", value=user.game)
    embed.add_field(name="Joined", value=user.joined_at)
    embed.add_field(name="Created", value=user.created_at)
    embed.add_field(name="Bot?", value=user.bot)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.message.author, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

with this, I hope I helped shorten your code and fix your problem, have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

I hope you didn't forget about [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html). To get the status you would need the precence intent.